# String index out of bounds java

Tags: java, string

I wrote the following piece of code but it gives me the StringIndexOutOfBounds exception, although I've put all the controls on the length of the string

```
for(int i=0; i<bits.length()-1; i++){
        k = i+1;
        while((bits.charAt(k)==bits.charAt(i)) && k<bits.length() ) {
            counter++;
            k++;
        }
        if(bits.charAt(i)=='1'&& counter % 3==0)
            morseCode.append('-');
        else if(bits.charAt(i)=='1')
            morseCode.append('.');

        counter = 1;
        }
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Have a closer look at variable `k`.

Comment: change your while condition to `while(k<bits.length() && (bits.charAt(k)==bits.charAt(i)) )`

Comment: String index out of range: 14, at line with the while() @khelwood

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing k value to i+1. At the last char of string when i will be `bits.length ()-1`, k will be bigger than the length of bits. You can initialize your `for` loop till `i-2` value so that k will not be out of bounds.